# XSD overrides SSIS

Tags: xml, ssis, xsd

I have a XML I'm reading into tables.  I have this XSD:

```
        <xs:element name="ListingDescription" 
                        type="xs:string" 
                        minOccurs="0" 
                        maxOccurs="1"> 
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>
                    This is a longer description of the listing.
                </xs:documentation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                    <retsid>101950</retsid>
                </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
```

for some reason I this case `xs:string` defaults to 255, and the data in the associated XML is larger than that.  I attempted to update the XMLSource stage in the SSIS package with larger lengths, but the xsd keeps overriding that back to 255.  How to I fix up `xs:string` into something that can feed into a nvarchar(4000)?

thanks

Comment: I think you're looking for the problem in the wrong place. Just because your schema allows long character strings doesn't mean SSIS will accept them. This is an SSIS questions, not an XML or XSD question: by your choice of question tags, you are directing the question at the wrong people.

Comment: How did you "[attempt] to update the XMLSource stage in the SSIS package with larger lengths"?

Comment: I did two things:  1. tried to change the datalength in SSIS's advanced editor in the XML Stage.  for some reason it kept reverting.  My attempt was going to nvarchar(MAX), then nvarchar(4000).  it reverted to Nvarchar(255) each time.  I assumed it was an XSD issue, so I looked there, but I can't find where to adjust.